# Bitbucket auto deploy to Linux server (DigitalOcean Droplet)

Tags: bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines, droplet

I have encountered a problem while attempting to deploy my code to a Droplet server (running Ubuntu) using BitBucket Pipeline.

I have set the necessary environment variables (SSH_PRIVATE_KEY, SSH_USER, SSH_HOST) and added the public key of the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the server. When I manually deploy from the server, there are no issues with cloning or pulling. However, during the automatic CI deployment stage, I am encountering the error shown in the attached image.

[image]

This is my .yml configuration.

[image]

Thanks for helps in advance.

Comment: Please paste your bitbucket-pipelines.yml as a code block, NOT as a screenshot image of your code. Also, please expand the failed script instruction to show the error message and, again, paste it as text and not as a screenshot image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to the values of the variables in defined in the configuration, you script should use `$VARIABLE_NAME`, not `VARIABLE_NAME` as that is literally that string.

```
- pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:latest
  variables:
    SSH_KEY: $SSH_KEY
    SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
    SERVER: $SSH_HOST
    COMMAND: "/app/deploy_dev01.sh"
```

Also, note some pitfalls exists when using an explicit `$SSH_KEY`, it is generally easier and safer to use the default key provided by Bitbucket, see [Load key "/root/.ssh/pipelines_id": invalid format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75156014/11715259)

Comment: Thanks for helping. As your following suggestion, it works now.